# Declaring variable makes OpenGL window close

Tags: c++, opengl

I'm just following a [tutorial](http://www.opengl-tutorial.org/beginners-tutorials/tutorial-2-the-first-triangle/) on beginner OpenGL and have encountered a rather weird issue: when i declare a `GLuint vertexArrayId` and try to generate and bind said id, the main window(just a black window) doesn't stay open anymore. My code:

```
#include <GL/glew.h>
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>
#include <GL/gl.h>
#include <GL/glu.h>
#include <cstdio>

const int WINDOW_HEIGHT = 600;
const int WINDOW_LENGTH = 800;

int main(int argc, char *args[])
{
    if (!glfwInit())
    {
        std::puts("Could not initialise GLFW");
        return -1;
    }

    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_SAMPLES, 4);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 3);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, 3);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE, GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE);

    GLFWwindow *window;
    window = glfwCreateWindow(WINDOW_LENGTH, WINDOW_HEIGHT, "Window", nullptr, nullptr);

//  GLuint vertexArrayId;
//  glGenVertexArrays(1, &vertexArrayId);
//  glBindVertexArray(vertexArrayId);

    if (nullptr == window)
    {
        std::puts("Could not initialize window");
        glfwTerminate();
    }

    glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);

    if(glewInit() != GLEW_OK){
        std::puts("Could not initialize GLEW");
        return -1;
    }

    glfwSetInputMode(window, GLFW_STICKY_KEYS, GL_TRUE);

    while(glfwGetKey(window, GLFW_KEY_ESCAPE) != GLFW_PRESS and glfwWindowShouldClose(window) == 0){

        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
        glfwSwapBuffers(window);
        glfwPollEvents();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

If i leave the code like this, the black window opens and stays open untill i press ESC key. If i were to uncomment that section, the window does not stay open anymore and closes as if there were no `while` loop. Because of this i cannot follow the tutorial and check further functionality that i'm trying to implement.

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: Try moving the `glGenVertexArrays` and `glBindVertexArray` calls to a point *after* the call to `glfwMakeContextCurrent` (and probably also after `glewInit`) as `glfwCreateWindow` doesn't set the current OpenGL context.

Comment: @G.M. fhat works, thank you. Where could i read more about this kind of behavior?

Comment: This is just basic OpenGL stuff I'm afraid so just keep reading the tutorials :-)  Having said that, the tutorial you link to does seem a bit 'scattered' with a lack of complete code examples.  [learnopengl.com](https://learnopengl.com/) is a site a lot of people recommend.  Not forgetting the [core spec](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/specs/gl/glspec46.core.pdf) of course.

Comment: This has nothing to do with OpenGL directly. YOur program _crashes_ in an attempt to dereference a NULL pointer.

Comment: @G.M. thanks, the amount of explanations in that site is significantly higher